# Trigger when user insert row in google sheet and return the list of new created row numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, event-handling

I use google script to capture event when user insert rows (in google sheet) and fetch the list of row number that's newly created.

I tried onChange :

```
function onInsertRow(e){
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") { 
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("insert");
  }
}
```

Trigger works but the event object of onChange() doesn't have range property. So how can i get the list of row numbers that has been inserted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the code:

1. you have to set up a new trigger.

you can use the getRow or geRowIndex to find out which row has changged.

Hope this will help.

```
function setUpTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('on_insert').forSpreadsheet('id').onChange().create();
}

function on_insert(e){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  sheet.appendRow([e.changeType,e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getRowIndex()])
}
```

Comment: I use onChange() because I tried using onEdit() and it can't be triggered when i insert rows. It works only when i edit the cells. How do you make it work ?

Comment: I updated the code above. You have to set up a trigger for this sheet. Then each time you made changes on this sheet, trigger will be fired.

Comment: So happy to help!